# Split image and compare each parts

Tags: python, numpy, math, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to divide an image into n equal parts and then compare each blocks to define an "equilibrium" in illustrations.
For example in the image shown below the bottom tends to be similar compared to the top.

[image]

I've written this but I got stuck and don't know what to do, any help?

```
import math
import io
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from PIL import Image
import image_slicer
from scipy import sum, average


tiles = image_slicer.slice('img/eq1.jpg', 2, save=False)
vectors = []
for tile in tiles:
    image = tile.image
    image = image.convert('RGB')

    colors = np.array(image).tolist()
    colors = [average(x, -1) for x in colors][0]

    vectors.append(colors)

#lista = np.array(tile.image)
#print np.array(tile.image)   

    image.show()

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

print cosine_similarity(vectors)
```

Comment: what is your problem? do you have any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i kind of solved it writing this:

```
import math
import io
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from PIL import Image
import image_slicer
from scipy import sum, average
from scipy.linalg import norm
import sklearn.metrics.pairwise


tiles = image_slicer.slice('img/ad.jpg', 4, save=False)
vectors = []
for tile in tiles:
    image = tile.image
    image = image.convert('RGB')

    colors = np.array(image).tolist()
    colors = [average(x, -1) for x in colors][0]

    vectors.append(colors)

#lista = np.array(tile.image)
#print np.array(tile.image)   

#    image.show()

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

print np.around(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances(vectors))
```